# Access role with multiple foreach not working

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter and data tables.

Let's talk about **Model** first.

I have total 4 access role which are `1,2,3,4` and I am displaying like this in the code.

```
$this->session->userdata['login_session']['access_role']==4
```

I already set the session for access role. So in the model, I am checking the access role first and then it will process for the next.

In the **Model**, There is no issue with `1,2,4` access role. I mean `if` condition and `else` condition is working perfectly.

Let's talk about `elseif` condition for access role `3` in model. I am getting more than one record in this condition. and my output is
[image]

So I added more than one foreach in the controller

```
 foreach($order_list as $r) { 
 //foreach($order as $r) { }// This foreach is commented and If I remove comment then it's working but 1,2,4 not working
}
```

So I have to display all the list which are in the access role 3.

**Model**

```
public function getCSRList($send_id){
if ($this->session->userdata['login_session']['access_role']==4) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_customer'); 
    $this->db->where('created_by',$send_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result_4 = $query->result();
    return $result_4; 
 }
  elseif ($this->session->userdata['login_session']['access_role']==3) {
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('tbl_employee');
    $this->db->where('team_leadername', $send_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    if($result)
      {
    $result_2= array();
    foreach($result as $id){
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('tbl_customer');
      $this->db->where('created_by',$id->id);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      $result_2[] = $query->result();
          }
       return $result_2;
      }
      else 
      {
        return 0;
      }
  }
 else{
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('tbl_customer');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      $result = $query->result();
      return $result;
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
    public function order_listdetails(){
      $send_id =$this->session->userdata['login_session']['id'];
      $order_list=$this->Customer_model->getCSRList($send_id);//getting from model

     // Datatables Variables
      $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
      $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
      $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));

      $data['draw'] = 1;
      $recordsTotal = count($order_list);
      $recordsFiltered = count($order_list);

      $data = array();
      $n=1;
      if(is_array($order_list)){
      foreach($order_list as $r) { 
      //foreach($order as $r) {// remove comment then working for 3 but not working for 1,2,4
      $encryption_id=base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($r->cust_id));

      if ($r->status == -1){
    $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
}
elseif($r->status == 0){
    $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
}
elseif($r->status == 1){
    $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
}
else{
    $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
}

if ($r->status_confirm == -1){
    $order_status_confirm='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
}
elseif($r->status_confirm == 3){
    $order_status_confirm='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
}
elseif($r->o_order_status_confirm == 1){
    $order_status_confirm='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
}
elseif($r->o_order_status_confirm == 2){
    $order_status_confirm='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
}
else{
    $order_status_confirm="";
}
$action='<a href="#">Action name</a>';

if ($r->follow == 1) {
$follow='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
}
else{
$follow='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
 }

               $data[] = array(
                        "Sr_No" => $n,
                        "cust_id" =>$encryption_id,//encrpt the id 
                        "Name"=>$r->c_firstname."".$r->c_lastname,
                        "Mobile"=>$r->c_mobileno,
                   "orderStatus"=>"<div class='in_oneLine'>".$order_status." ".$order_status_confirm."</div>",
                        "action"=>"<div class='in_oneLine'>".$action." ".$follow."</div>"
                   );
                   $n++;
              }
        }
    //}
      $output = array(
         "draw" => $draw,
         "recordsTotal" => $recordsTotal,
         "recordsFiltered" =>$recordsFiltered,
         "data" => $data
                );
        echo json_encode($output);
         exit();
    }
```

Comment: from where you got $order data

Comment: @Sachin, I tried foreach($order_list as $order) {  foreach($order as $r) { }} and it's working..but not working for 1,2,4

Comment: so you want retrive above printed array right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. even I am getting from model but not able to display in controller

Comment: can you share your printed array in text instead of the image so i can provide you correct solution

Comment: It's big. This sit is not allowed me. it's asking for more description

Answer (score 0):

Update your foreach code with below code

```
$data = array();
foreach($order_list as $order) { 
  if(is_array($order)){
    foreach($order as $r) {
      $encryption_id=base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($r->cust_id));
       if ($r->status == -1){
          $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }elseif($r->status == 0){
          $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }elseif($r->status == 1){
          $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }else{
          $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }

       if ($r->status_confirm == -1){
          $order_status_confirm='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }elseif($r->status_confirm == 3){
          $order_status_confirm='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }elseif($r->o_order_status_confirm == 1){
          $order_status_confirm='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }elseif($r->o_order_status_confirm == 2){
          $order_status_confirm='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }else{
          $order_status_confirm="";
       }

       $action='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       if ($r->follow == 1) {
          $follow='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }else{
          $follow='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }

       $data[] = array(
                 "Sr_No" => $n,
                 "cust_id" =>$encryption_id,//encrpt the id 
                 "Name"=>$r->c_firstname."".$r->c_lastname,
                 "Mobile"=>$r->c_mobileno,
                 "orderStatus"=>"<div class='in_oneLine'>".$order_status." ".$order_status_confirm."</div>",
                 "action"=>"<div class='in_oneLine'>".$action." ".$follow."</div>"
        );
        $n++;
    }
  }else{
    $encryption_id=base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($order->cust_id));
       if ($order->status == -1){
          $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }elseif($order->status == 0){
          $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }elseif($order->status == 1){
          $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }else{
          $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }

       if ($order->status_confirm == -1){
          $order_status_confirm='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }elseif($order->status_confirm == 3){
          $order_status_confirm='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }elseif($order->o_order_status_confirm == 1){
          $order_status_confirm='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }elseif($order->o_order_status_confirm == 2){
          $order_status_confirm='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }else{
          $order_status_confirm="";
       }

       $action='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       if ($order->follow == 1) {
          $follow='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }else{
          $follow='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
       }

       $data[] = array(
                 "Sr_No" => $n,
                 "cust_id" =>$encryption_id,//encrpt the id 
                 "Name"=>$order->c_firstname."".$order->c_lastname,
                 "Mobile"=>$order->c_mobileno,
                 "orderStatus"=>"<div class='in_oneLine'>".$order_status." ".$order_status_confirm."</div>",
                 "action"=>"<div class='in_oneLine'>".$action." ".$follow."</div>"
        );
        $n++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Give me some time to understand your answer

Comment: Sure take your own time.

Comment: Yes, I am getting the output correct but now I am not able to get the out of 1,2,4

Comment: not getting what you sey can you please explain more clear?

Comment: you mean in role 1,2,4 there is no inside array right?

Comment: When  $this->session->userdata['login_session']['access_role']==3 then I am getting the output using your code. but when $this->session->userdata['login_session']['access_role']==4 or else then your code is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183782/discussion-between-user9437856-and-sachin).

Comment: I am struggling for my if else condition because I don't want to use twice code. I can understand only one if else condition but there are more then 10 conditions

Comment: you added if else code in if condition as well as else condition.

Comment: actual I have to use for both and code is also same..it's increasing the line of code. In the case, in future, if I change anything in the condition or text then I have to update in both conditions.